# Getting a fatal error (Maximum execution time) on php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\module2\conference_publication_view.php on line 71`

Already tried different method nothing worked.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM patent_details WHERE patent_id = '$pID[$pid]'";
$result = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );

if( $result) {    **//Line 71**
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $patent_id = $row['patent_id'];
        $authors = $row['authors'];
```

Anybody have solution please reply. Thanks.

Comment: Can you test your query on a mysql client ? So to check if it is really a slow query. If so try to make it faster by choosing only the columns you need or filter more results.

Comment: You want to optimize your code or to remove max_execution time?

Comment: @farbiondriven the code working perfectly on mysql client but not on the page

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase max_execution_time in php.ini. The default setting of 30 seconds is often insufficient.